# Two subsub categories in select optgroup and moving their values to another one select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need two sub categories in select optgroup working for moving them into the second one select.

This is what I have:

CSS:

```
.sub-sub-optgroup{
 text-indent: 15px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select multiple id="resort" class="w100p" size="50">                
                <optgroup label="Group 1">
                    <option id="el1" value="1">Option 1a</option>                            
                    <!-- THIS IS WHAT I NEED -->
                    <optgroup label="Group 1B" class="sub-sub-optgroup">
                      <option id="el2" value="2">Option 1b</option>
                    </optgroup>
                    <!-- END -->
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Group 2">
                    <option id="el3" value="3">Option 2a</option>
                    <option id="el4" value="4">Option 2b</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Group 3">
                    <option id="el5" value="5">Option 1a</option>
                    <option id="el6" value="6">Option 1b</option>
                </optgroup>  
            </select>
        </td>
        <td> 
            <input type="button" class="noarrow" id="add" value=">" /><br />
            <input type="button" class="noarrow" id="remove" value="<" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <select multiple id="resort_select" class="w100p" size="50">                        
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
  <script>
            var $select1 = $('#resort');
            var $select2 = $('#resort_select');

            $("select optgroup").click(function (e) { /* clicking on outgroup and automacilly select child */
                if ($(e.target).is("optgroup")) {
                    $(this).children("option").attr("selected", "selected");
                }
            });

            /* By default */
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#el3,#el5").attr("selected", "selected");           
                 processOptions($select1, $select2, false); 
                $("#el3,#el5").removeAttr("selected");
            });


            $([$select1, $select2]).each(function () {
                $(this).find('optgroup').each(function (idx) {
                    var ogId = 'og' + idx;
                    $(this).attr('id', ogId);
                    $(this).find('option').each(function () {
                        $(this).data('parent', ogId);
                    });
                });
            });

            $('#add').click(function () {
                processOptions($select1, $select2, false);
            });
            $('#remove').click(function () {
                processOptions($select2, $select1, true);
            });

            var optgFoundInTarget = {};

            function processOptions(source, target, variable) {
                var selectedOptions = $(source).find('option:selected');
                if (selectedOptions.length) {
                    selectedOptions.each(function () {
                        var movingFromOptGroup = $(this).parent();
                        parentOg = $(movingFromOptGroup).attr('id');
                        if (parentOg.indexOf('_target') > -1) {
                            parentOg = parentOg.replace('_target', '');
                        } else {
                            parentOg += '_target';
                        }
                        if (typeof optgFoundInTarget[parentOg] == 'object') {
                        } else {
                            if (target.find('optgroup#' + parentOg).length) {
                                _el = target.find('optgroup#' + parentOg);
                            } else {
                                _el = $('<optgroup id="' + $(movingFromOptGroup).attr('id') + '_target" label="' + $(movingFromOptGroup).attr('label') + '" />').appendTo(target);
                            }
                            optgFoundInTarget[parentOg] = _el;
                        }
                        targetOptGroup = optgFoundInTarget[parentOg];
                        if (variable) {
                            $(this).data('parent', $(targetOptGroup).attr('id')).remove(); 
                        } else {  
                            $(this).data('parent', $(targetOptGroup).attr('id')).clone(true).appendTo(targetOptGroup);
                        }
                    });
                    $([source, target]).each(function () {
                        $(this).find('optgroup').each(function () {
                            $(this).css('display', $(this).find('option').length ? 'inline' : 'none');
                        })
                    });
                    target.val(null);
                }
                orderOptgroups();
                removeDuplicity();
            }
            /* removing duplicity */
            function removeDuplicity() {
                var usedNames = {}; 
                $("#resort_select optgroup option").each(function () {
                    if (usedNames[$(this).attr("id")]) {
                        $(this).remove();
                    } else {
                        usedNames[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).attr("id");
                    }
                });
            }
            /* sorting alphabetically */
            function orderOptgroups() {
                $("#resort_select").each(function () {
                    var $select = $(this);
                    var $groups = $select.find("optgroup");
                    $groups.remove();
                    $groups = $groups.sort(function (g1, g2) {
                        return g1.label.localeCompare(g2.label);
                    });
                    $select.append($groups);
                    $groups.each(function () {
                        var $group = $(this);
                        var options = $group.find("option");
                        options.remove();
                        options = options.sort(function (a, b) {
                            return a.innerHTML.localeCompare(b.innerHTML);
                        });
                        $group.append(options);
                    });
                });
            }

        </script>
```

Now It works only for a one sub category. I need it to make it working for two sub categories. It means: I click on "Group 1B" (everything inside is automatically selected) then I press right arrow button and It moves to the another one html select, but It moves WRONG. Because only "Group 1B" moves, but I also need "Group 1" (parent) to be moved.